# Why is my printer unable to print on glossy paper?

Tags: printing, ink-jet

My printer is unable to print on glossy paper, resulting in prints like:

[image]

The printer is a HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3525, and the paper is 240 GSM "High Glossy Inkjet Photo Paper" marked as "Water Resistant, Super White Instant Dry" (in case it matters).

While printing, I chose "HP Everyday Photo Paper, Glossy" (though the paper I'm using is not from HP, this seemed like the closest option):

[image]

When that didn't work, I also tried "Other photo papers", to no avail. These seem like the only options that seem to match my paper.

How do I get my printer to print on this paper?

Comment: As I wrote, it's a HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3525. It has only one black. And it's the same cartridge type I've been using for a few years — HP 685, purchased straight from HP, so it's unlikely to be a fake. I checked both the labels on the cartridge and what the printer reports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turns out to have a simple, non-technical, amusing answer: I was loading the paper upside down. The glossy side should be face down, but I'd loaded it face up. Once I fixed that, it started working.